# Matrix transformation with raster layers in R

Tags: r, matrix, transformation, raster

I am following some code using a matrix transformation with an input of type num:

```
> input
1     101.3862407     63.8025351
2     -39.2936491      0.3279252
3     -2.5526003      1.8761791
4     36.1441720     45.3625071
....
```

And a transformation matrix:

```
transfmatrix <- matrix(c(0.9,-0.1,0.1,0.9),nrow=2)

> transfmatrix
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  0.9  0.1
 [2,] -0.1  0.9
```

I can then do a data transformation using:

```
# transformation
result <-input%*%transfmatrix
```

This works fine, but I would like "input" to be a raster file. 
Is it possible to apply a similar transformation to raster layers? I tried the following:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))

test1<-stack(r,r*2)
test2 <- test1%*%transfmatrix
```

but received an error:

```
Error in test1 %*% transf.m : 
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

Comment: added object transfmatrix

Comment: test2 <- raster(as.matrix(test1)%*%as.matrix(transfmatrix) ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a 2-column matrix from your data to multiply by the 2x2 matrix. Perhaps this:

```
> z = as.matrix(test1) %*% transf.m
> dim(z)
  [1] 800   2
```

That makes an 800x2 matrix from the 800 cells of `test1`.

If you want a raster stack with the values, then, overwriting `test1`, do:

```
> test1[[1]][]=z[,1]
> test1[[2]][]=z[,2]
```